# Ubuntu Private Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, cloud

I am trying to play around with Ubuntu's private cloud and have some questions.

1. Do I have to install the server edition for the private cloud?
2. Is it free?
3. Does any one know of any tutorial or guide on setting it up that isn't just marketing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, all editions of Ubuntu have access to the same repositories so ultimate any install is capable of anything. I would suggest using reading up on the documentation about [Ubuntu Cloud infrastructure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure). There is also a USB live image that can be installed.
2. Yes. The cloud software in the current version of Ubuntu is based on [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/), which is freely available and open source.
3. See the above links for basic documentation, or ask new questions here for specific stumbling blocks.